Visual Studio 2022 space required but has the close button
I'm experiencing an issue with the Visual Studio 2022 installer. After the installation completes, the installer displays "99MB remaining" in the "space required" label in the lower right corner, rather than showing 0MB as expected. Additionally, the button labeled "Modify" (which I expected to see to complete the installation) instead displays as "Close," leaving me unable to proceed.
Here's what I’ve tried so far:

I added the .NET 4.8 SDK to force the "Modify" button to appear, which allowed me to proceed, but after installation, the space required increased from 384MB to over 600MB instead of going down to 0MB.
I uninstalled and reinstalled the Visual Studio instance, but the issue persists.
I have not yet uninstalled the Visual Studio Installer itself, as I’d prefer to avoid that step if possible.

Question:
Has anyone encountered this issue, and is there a way to resolve it without uninstalling the Visual Studio Installer? Any insights on why the space required label isn’t reaching 0MB?

Microsoft stuff is pretty macro these days and loves to fetch more bloat from the internet. You could try to do a layout, building yourself an offline installer for a bit more determinism of the downloads and caches. Ultimately the most predictable/sensible result would be installing it on another system and repacking it yourself.
